# How to search for 3 specific things within a file?

Tags: shell-script, grep, pipe, file-search

Within the file, `security.log` I need to find how many IP addresses have the most DNSBL 5 rankings.
This is what a line in this file can look like:

```
Oct 24 00:00:28 MAIL-00 postfix/postscreen[10909]: dnsbl rank 5 for [103.129.47.51]:50807
```

To filter out IP addresses with DNSBL rankings, I did:

```
grep "ip" security.log | grep -i "DNSBL" security.log
```

Or I could write a shell script to help, I was thinking something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

#grep every ip with "dnsbl rank 5"
#count the amount of times each unique one appears, create variable with IP and value is the number of times it appears
#Find the variable with the biggest value and output the variable name to screen
```

The script would need to cut out the other stuff, so the output to search from is just a list of IPs that had "dnsbl ran 5" before it.  I haven't used `cut` in a long time, would that be the best way to only get the IP inside the brackets?

If someone could help me out, I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! When asking for help parsing data, you really need to show us an example of the data you are trying to parse. Since we don't know what the lines look like, we can't help you. So please [edit] your question, add a few representative lines of your `security.log` (obfuscate any IPs or other sensitive data by replacing them with `1.2.3.4` or whatever) and the output you expect. Make sure to include some lines that should be kept and some that should be removed, and use the [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format the examples as code.

Answer (score 1):

If the lines are all consistently similar to the line you showed, you could do something like this:

```
sed -nE 's/.*dnsbl rank 5.*\[([0-9\.]+)\].*/\1/pi' test.log | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -n 1
```

The sed command prints only those lines containing 'dnsbl rank 5', but gets rid of everything except what's in the pair of brackets following that phrase, then the first sort commands puts all matches together, the uniq command counts the number of matches for each ip, the second sort puts them in order and the head command takes the top 1.

The output should be somethinglike:
    `4 103.129.47.51`
If there are four occurrences of that IP address with dnsbl rank 5 and that's more than any of the others.

This doesn't really account for ties, however, and the data would have to be consistently formatted.

Comment: Piping to sort and unique is very clever!  I tried it out and it worked!  You're awesome, thank you so much! 

Answer (score -1):

```
awk '/dnsbl rank 5/{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if ($i ~ /[0-9]{1,}\.[0-9]{1,}\.[0-9]{1,}\.[0-9]{1,}/){gsub(/\].*/,"",$i);gsub(/\[/,"",$i);print $i}}}' filename| awk '{a[$1]++}END{for(x in a){print x,a[x]}}'| sort -k2 -nr
```

This may helps

Comment: Would you mind explaining what this is supposed to do? Without some explanation, this doesn’t help.

Comment: (1) It should go without saying that I agree with @StephenKitt that this should be explained. (2) Do you have the impression that we *prefer* long, convoluted, complicated and cryptic answers here?  ***WE  DO  NOT!***  The above should be spread out over about 18 lines, with added spaces, for readability.  And, again, you’re running two `awk` processes, one piped into the other.  You don’t need to do that.  And GNU `awk` has a built-in sorting capability, so you don’t need to pipe into `sort`.